Generating Wrapped Object Format with Swagger Annotations
I'm using the Restlet Framework 2.4.3 along with the org.restlet.ext.swagger extension to generate Swagger documentation for my API. I have a User model that looks like this:
@ApiModel
@XStreamAlias("user")
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    private int userId;
    private String username;

    // Getters and setters
}

The problem is that Swagger generates the documentation like this:
{
  "userId": 1,
  "username": "sample_username"
}

However, I need the output to be wrapped in a "user" object, like this:
{
    "user": {
        "userId": 1,
        "username": "sample_username"
    }
}

The @XStreamAlias("user") annotation is important for my project and can't be removed or changed. How can I configure Swagger (using the org.restlet.ext.swagger extension) to generate the documentation with the desired wrapped format?
Additional Information:

I'm also using the org.restlet.ext.xstream plugin.

I've searched through the documentation and tried various approaches, but none have worked so far. Any insights or suggestions on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

Create a wrapper class that contains the User object?

Can't wrap it because we use XStream
